# Thesis -style Navigation

Tags: theme-development, menus, admin, themes

I am working on a theme where I would like users to be able to select pages to show in the theme options page much like Thesis.

I've been Googling / reverse engineering Thesis for a couple hours but haven't found a great solution. I am wondering if anyone has done this or has seen a tutorial.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in a custom theme:

```
<h3>Select pages to include in menu:</h3>

<p>
<?php
$page_ids = get_all_page_ids();
$current_selected = get_option("pages_to_include");

foreach( $page_ids as $page_id ) {
    if( get_post_status( $page_id ) == 'publish' ) {
        $checked = ( !empty( $current_selected ) && in_array( $page_id, $current_selected ) ) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="page_to_include[]" id="page-' . $page_id . '" value="' . $page_id . '"' . $checked . ' /> <label for="page-' . $page_id . '">' . get_the_title( $page_id ) . '</label><br />';
    }
}
?>
</p>
```

You store the pages list in an option (here is `"pages_to_include"`).

Comment: Excellent I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 3.0 there has been a custom menu feature, does that fit your needs? Or something in it that doesn't fit your needs? See [Appearance Menus SubPanel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) in the WordPress codex

Comment: I need this functionality in an admin options page so the user can select pages to include in a slider

Comment: Doesn't custom menus do this, minus the fact that it will always be under Appearance > Menus (to be honest I have not used them yet)? I'd assume it's better to not reinvent the wheel if not needed as users should be looking there for customizing a menu (if your target is WordPress 3.0 or newer).